# AWS Codebuild - using pwsh.exe (powershell 7) instead of powershell.exe (powershell 5) as the default shell

Tags: powershell, aws-codebuild

In AWS Codebuild, I am calling the AWS provided managed image "Windows Server Core 2019" as shown here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html

In my buildspec.yml, I ran the powershell command `$PSVersionTable`

And the console output output indicates it's running PS Version 5.1 as shown:

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1490                                  
PSEdition                      Desktop                                         
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1490                                 
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

However, I need Powershell 7 as it has an enhancement that I need that is absent in Powershell 5.1.

However, I can see Powershell 7 is installed when I ran the command `pwsh.exe -c '$PSVersionTable'`  in my buildspec.yml. The following output was observed:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.1.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

So I know PS 7 is there. But how do I switch to pwsh.exe (PS 7) as my default shell as opposed to powershell.exe (PS 5)?

Looking at the AWS Codebuild documentation, it stated that the only supported shell for Windows Image is cmd.exe and powershell.exe:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

Am I out of luck?